# Как в QTreeWidget в C++ добавить новый элемент New preset 2, находясь на позиции New preset 1?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть QTreeWidget, состоящий из элементов в разделе "Select preset": New section 0, New section 1 и элементов New preset 0, New preset 1 ...
Как мне добавить новый элемент New preset 2 в раздел New section 1, находясь при этом на позиции New preset 1 (как показано на скрине).

Имеющиеся команды indexOfTopLevelItem() и currentIndex() не позволяют мне получить индекс New section 1, когда курсор находится на позиции New preset 1. Если-бы я получил этот индекс, проблема была бы решена.

Уточнение: добавленный элемент должен находится в той же колонке, что и New preset 0, New preset 1 (т.е. по такому же принципу, как это выглядит в New section 0)

[image: QTreeWidget]

Comment: [`QTreeWidgetItem::parent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#parent) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
new QTreeWidgetItem(currentIndex()->parent(), {"New preset 2"});
```

На практике, само собой, надо будет добавить соответствующих проверок.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо! совсем забыл про конструкцию currentIndex()->parent().